# Replacing Data in Rows and Columns with Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for help.  I am new to gScript coding.  I have been research how to do specific things, but this code seem to be very slow. Added comments for each line to try to help others understand loops.

Any help would be great.  I know there is a much easier way to do this, but just don't know how.

```
function best1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Platform"),
      range = sheet.getDataRange(),
      values = range.getValues();

  //Start loop from row 3 stoping at row 54  
  for (var i = 3; i < 54; i++) {
  //start loop from column 37 "AL" to 57 "BE"
      for (var j = 37; j < 57; j++) {

        //find all data in loops
        var data = values [i][j];
        //find value in active row and column 34 "AI" 
        var v1 = values [i][34]
        //find value in active row and column 35 "AJ"
        var v2 = values [i][35];
        //find value in active row and column 36 "AK"
        var v3 = values [i][36];

   //Compare active value to not null
    if (values [i ][34] !== "" ){
   //Check for blank spot   
     if (data === ""){
   //Find blank spot and replace it with active value
       sheet.getRange(i+1, j+1).setValue(v1);
   //Re-call all data due to change
       values = range.getValues();
   //Set active value to null
       sheet.getRange(i+1, 34+1).setValue("");
   //Re-call all data due to change
       var v1 = values [i][34];  
     }
    }

   //Compare active value to not null     
     if (values [i ][35] != ""){
   //Check for blank spot    
     if (data == ""){
   //Find blank spot and replace it with active value    
       sheet.getRange(i+1, j+1).setValue(v2);
   //Re-call all data due to change    
       values = range.getValues();
   //Set active value to null    
       sheet.getRange(i+1, 35+1).setValue("");
   //Re-call all data due to change    
       var v2 = values [i][35];  
    }
   }   

    //Start loop from row 3 stoping at row 54     
    for (var x = 3; x < 54; x++) {
    //start loop from column 37 "AL" to 57 "BE"  
      for (var r = 37; r < 57; r++){

    //Compare active value to not null    
      if (values [i ][34] !== "" ){
    //Compare active value if greater than lowest value    
        if (v1 >= v3)
    //Compare lowest value to current data      
          if (v3 == values [i][j]){
    //Set active value to null       
            sheet.getRange(i+1, 34+1).setValue("");
     //Find blank spot and replace it with active value        
            sheet.getRange(i+1, j+1).setValue(v1);
     //Re-call all data due to change       
            values = range.getValues();
     //Re-call all data due to change      
            var v1 = values [i][34];
       }
      }
     }

     //Compare active value to not null 
        if (values [i ][35] !== "" ){
     //Compare active value if greater than lowest value      
              if (v2 >= v3){
     //Compare lowest value to current data           
                if (v3 === values [i][j]){
     //Set active value to null
                  sheet.getRange(i+1, 35+1).setValue("");
     //Find blank spot and replace it with active value             
                  sheet.getRange(i+1, j+1).setValue(v2);
      //Re-call all data due to change           
                  values = range.getValues();
      //Re-call all data due to change            
                  var v1 = values [i][35];
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: show us your attempt at using getValues instead. google for apps script best practices in the documentation.

Comment: Agree with Zig. It's much more efficient to use `.getValues()` and iterate through the array than to call an individual cell value over and over

Comment: Edited the above code.